# Merge arrays inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Going through the link [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript) is somewhat what i need. But with that link and many other links shows merging of arrays of two arrays. What I have is as follows

```
[
   {
      "setter":[
         {
            "keyname":"Sample Size",
            "cond":"=",
            "value":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "setter":[
         {
            "joinedcond":"and"
         },
         {
            "keyname":"Sample Size",
            "cond":"=",
            "value":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

That is I have an array and inside that array I have an array "setter".
What I want is actually merging all setter array as a single array. Having said the merge should produce below output

```
[
   {
      "setter":[
         {
            "keyname":"Sample Size",
            "cond":"=",
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "joinedcond":"and"
         },
         {
            "keyname":"Sample Size",
            "cond":"=",
            "value":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you really need an array for the final output ? Can it not be a simple object with a `setter` property ?

Comment: @Weedoze Unfortunately no...

Comment: ok no problems !  I provided you a solution to generate an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `Array#reduce`

```js
var arr = [{"setter":[{"keyname":"Sample Size","cond":"=","value":1}]},{"setter":[{"joinedcond":"and"},{"keyname":"Sample Size","cond":"=","value":2}]}];

var finalArr = arr.reduce((a,x)=>{
  (a[0].setter = a[0].setter || []).push(...x.setter);
  return a;
},[{}]);

console.log(finalArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked. Want to know couple of things 1) ... exactly inside push does ? 2) Will it be faster ?

Comment: @Neo `...` is the spread operator (Check the doc). I am using it inside the `push` function to push all the array instead of looping setter to push each item one by one. Faster compared to what ?

Comment: Got that... I was actually hoping will it be faster than for loop. But guess the spread operator did the trick, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the outer keys and concat the inner values with a dynamic approach for the outer keys, like `setter`.

```js
var data = [{ setter: [{ keyname: "Sample Size", cond: "=", value: 1 }] }, { setter: [{ joinedcond: "and" }, { keyname: "Sample Size", cond: "=", value: 2 }] }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, o) {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                if (!hash[k]) {
                    hash[k] = {};
                    r.push(hash[k]);
                }
                hash[k][k] = (hash[k][k] || []).concat(o[k]);
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 Rest and Spread operators we can achieve the same with a recursive function call:

```
let cdata= data.slice();//Copy the data
let condensedArray=[];

function flatten(data, ...rest){
    let [{ setter }] = data; 
    condensedArray = [...condensedArray, ...setter];
    data.splice(0,1); 
    data.length>0?flatten(data, ...data):console.log('Complete');
}

flatten(cdata, ...cdata);
console.log(condensedArray);
```